# Is there any possible to create master node in one aws region and worker node in another region?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is there any possibility to create cluster with **eks** in one region (eg. `ap-south-1`) and join worker node from another region (eg. `ap-north-east-2`). If yes, can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. It's because you have no power to change anything on **master node**.

**Amazon EKS** is fully managed **Kubernetes service**, you would need to make your own cluster on **EC2** instances.

Comment: But I'm not going to change the master node , master node will be in the same region , I need to join worker node from the another region

Comment: You are not able to manually add new nodes so you cannot choose where they be located at. You can scale up the cluster but this will be done automatically.

Comment: Thankyou@ShantyMan

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, even with self-managed node groups, because the node in the distant region is unable to authenticate to join the cluster.

This authentication is performed by a component called [`aws-iam-authenticator`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator), which is one of the Kubernetes master components that EKS runs for you. When a node tries to join the cluster, `aws-iam-authenticator` tries to map the IAM role that the node authenticates with to a Kubernetes username, `system:node:<nodename>`. `<nodename>` must precisely match the name of the node, which is its private EC2 DNS name. In order to generate this username, `aws-iam-authenticator` looks up the private DNS name of the node using the EC2 API, but it does so in the same region as the EKS cluster, so it will fail for a node that is trying to join from another region.

It would be possible to patch this behaviour in `aws-iam-authenticator`, but since AWS runs this component for you as part of the EKS master components, you can't run a patched version.

You can of course achieve a multi-region K8s cluster by deploying your own cluster without using EKS. However, there are risks with distant nodes. If the two regions lose network connectivity with each other, or latency increases beyond a certain amount, then control plane operations involving the nodes in the distant region will fail and the master will see those nodes as lost. Among other things, this means that pods that were running on the distant nodes may be rescheduled elsewhere despite still actually running in the distant region. Note that connectivity could be lost or impaired between the regions even while both regions still had connectivity to other parts of the Internet.

You should deploy another cluster in the second region. There are [various solutions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/tree/master/sig-multicluster#subprojects-1) under SIG Multicluster for federating the clusters allowing them to be managed together.